How can i monitor changes in variables python
I have two files that i input as pandas DFs in my code, where the first one has different product categories and the products in stock:



Name
Stock




ART



Paintings
20


Ceramics
10


BOOKS



Poetry
50


Fantasy
32


History
15



While the second one has a constant stream of prices:



Name
Price




Paintings
100


Ceramics
70


Paintings
130


Poetry
17


Fantasy
22


Ceramics
58


History
19


History
12



I am trying to output as a stream the prices of the products, and also the total price of the product category while those prices change.
So essentially as my code reads through the second dataFrame it would output as it goes:
Paintings: 2000 
Ceramics: 700
ART: 2700 (2000+700)
Paintings:2600
ART: 3300 (2600+700)
Poetry: 850
Fantasy: 704 (22*32)
Ceramics: 580
ART: 3180 (2600+580)
History: 285
BOOKS: 2419 (850 +704 +580 +285)
History: 180 (12*15)
BOOKS: 2314 (850 +704 +580 +180)

i understand i can just do that using for loops, but how do i monitor which products belong to which category and hence the total category price?
Is there a way to optimise this by only monitoring the change in a product's price (old-new) and adding that to the category sum ?
Any help/ advice would I would be really grateful!

Just to add, the second table that contains the prices is a variable one as new rows are added on to it.

There is one point that is not quite clear. If your price list will always be with the latest prices, you can use it with a code like prices.drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last').
Your prices dataframe hasn't good type information. You can imagine all good names are identical and categorical.
But, these code blocks can work for your case.
Create the sample data
import pandas as pd

goods = {
    'ART': pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'Name': ['Paintings', 'Ceramics'],
            'Stock': [20, 10]
        }
    ),
    'BOOKS': pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'Name': ['Poetry', 'Fantasy', 'History'],
            'Stock': [50, 32, 15]
        }
    )
}


prices = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['Paintings', 'Ceramics', 'Paintings', 'Poetry', 'Fantasy', 'Ceramics', 'History', 'History'],
        'Price': [100, 70, 130, 17, 22, 58, 19, 12]
    }
)

You can use this code for running row by row.
from typing import Dict


def print_specific_way(total_stock_prices: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]) -> None:
    # you can update this block with specific conditions and printing alternatives
    categorical_total_prices = {category: sum(stock_prices.values()) for category, stock_prices in total_stock_prices.items()}
    message = f'Total price of stock: {sum(categorical_total_prices.values()):,.2f} - ['
    message += ' - '.join(f'{key}: {value:,.2f}' for key, value in  categorical_total_prices.items() if value != 0)
    message += ']'
    print(message)


stock_prices = {category: {} for category in goods.keys()}

for price_tag in prices.itertuples(index=False):
    for category, df in goods.items():
        cond = df['Name'] == price_tag.Name

        # if the name can't match any rows continue
        if cond.sum() == 0:
            continue

        # get the stock of good and multiply with price information
        stock = df[cond].iloc[0]['Stock']  # if the good list is unique this line is good enough
        stock_prices[category][price_tag.Name] = stock * price_tag.Price

        break

    # print after all price updates for stock
    print_specific_way(stock_prices)

Output of example:
Total price of stock: 2,000.00 - [ART: 2,000.00]
Total price of stock: 2,700.00 - [ART: 2,700.00]
Total price of stock: 3,300.00 - [ART: 3,300.00]
Total price of stock: 4,150.00 - [ART: 3,300.00 - BOOKS: 850.00]
Total price of stock: 4,854.00 - [ART: 3,300.00 - BOOKS: 1,554.00]
Total price of stock: 4,734.00 - [ART: 3,180.00 - BOOKS: 1,554.00]
Total price of stock: 5,019.00 - [ART: 3,180.00 - BOOKS: 1,839.00]
Total price of stock: 4,914.00 - [ART: 3,180.00 - BOOKS: 1,734.00]

Note: I recommend you to work with a simpler and more performant code block. For this, you will need to fully understand your needs and determine your data structure accordingly.
